# Debug level information fails to output in VS Code

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

In the `ConfigureServices` method I'm using:

```
var loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory();   
loggerFactory.AddDebug();
```

However, use of `LogDebug()` fails to output to the debug console.

Comment: I cannot speak on behalf of Visual Studio Code for sure but it is text editor, a very awesome one, the best IMO. I wouldn't use it for debugging C# code though much, it wouldn't be my first choice at least. Download the free Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition and see if you get outputs...

Comment: In VS 2017 the same problem arises; however, the answer provided below works for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than rely on AddDebug()... specify the **minimum log level** with AddConsole() and the debug level information outputs to the console as expected:

```
loggerFactory.AddConsole(LogLevel.Debug);
```

This works because the methods AddConsole(), AddDebug() etc. only specify *where* to log information.  The issue is discussed in more depth [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/issues/275).