# LogDebug to Debug Console in VS Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I cannot seem to log debug statements to the "Debug Console" in VS Code using dotnet core. I have this statement in my Startup.cs:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILogger<Startup> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        ...
    }
```

When I print this statement from

```
_logger.LogInformation("Testing LogInformation");
```

I get output in the Debug Console, but when I run this statement:

```
_logger.LogDebug("Testing LogDebug");
```

nothing shows. I would like to do a lot of debug statements which don't carry over to production, unless I configure it to run debug statements. It seems like this would be a configuration setting. I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48938036/debug-level-information-fails-to-output-in-vs-code) but it does not make sense to me. I seems very intuitive that the LogDebug would show a statement in the Debug Console, and if the challenge, as a [link in the post](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/issues/275) states, is that "If the default was Debug or Verbose then a typical request would have hundreds of log messages flowing through, and that would probably make the log output unusable in most cases.", that challenge should be dealt with in a different way, like being able to filter the component for which debug statements are shown.

Am I missing a configuration option? Are others using LogInformation?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure this behavior using the file `appsettings.Development.json` which is located in the root directory of your appplication. In section "Logging" you find a subsection "LogLevel" with attribute "Default" which is set to "Information" by default. If you change this to "Debug", you will also see the output of `LogDebug`. For more information, see [Logging in .NET Core and ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#configure-logging).